# Is it possible to add specific restrictions to an application that requires administrator privileges on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, privileges

I have seen people say that giving applications high privilege levels can be pretty dangerous. However, is it possible to allow an application to have administrator privileges but simultaneously restrict some of the privileges? Such as, for example: "this application needs administrator privileges but I want to make sure it can't do a few things such as read/write in a specific folder".

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: A process permissions are controlled by the user’s permissions.  If the user used to elevated the permissions of the process are restricted then so will the permissions of the elevated permissions

Comment: Does this mean we can't give applications requiring administrator privilege a sort of neutered administrator privilege? We have to kinda-sorta do it through a user?